# orientdb local node not master

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

We're using OrientDB in a cluster with 5 nodes with the Java API libraries on top of it. Both of them are using version 2.2.8, and we're using Tinkerpop Blueprints version 2.6.0. We're experiencing a strange issue where the database runs fine for some time, then we suddenly start encountering the error below. We have only started experiencing this issue since we upgraded to 2.2 from 1.7.

I was wondering whether anyone else has experienced this issue / error before, or if anyone had any advice on what we might need to change to get a multi-node environment working.

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedConfigurationChangedException: Local node 'aNode' is not the master for cluster 'aCluster' (it is 'anotherNode')
    DB name="dbName"
    DB name="dbName"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:428)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:379)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:261)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:153)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:2133)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$28.execute(OStorageRemote.java:1316)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$28.execute(OStorageRemote.java:1289)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$2.execute(OStorageRemote.java:198)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:230)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:195)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.commit(OStorageRemote.java:1289)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:560)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:106)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2733)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2703)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.commit(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:175)
```

Comment: What operation are you doing? Is it a save on specific cluster?

Comment: The previous operation is to add an edge using Blueprints OrientVertex, then calling commit on the graph.

Comment: Could you post the default-distributed-db-config.json ?

Comment: Could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: Issue raised - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6765

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing something similar in a two-node scenario. On saving document (Java API) on node1, I get the error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedConfigurationChangedException: Local node 'node1' is not the master for cluster 'event_3' (it is 'node2')
    DB name="********"
    DB name="********"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:428)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:379)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:261)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:153)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:2133)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$6.execute(OStorageRemote.java:543)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$6.execute(OStorageRemote.java:537)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$1.execute(OStorageRemote.java:166)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:230)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.asyncNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:158)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createRecord(OStorageRemote.java:523)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeSaveRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2075)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveNew(OTransactionNoTx.java:246)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:179)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2598)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:103)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1800)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1791)
    (... stack trace truncated here ...)
```

Java code where exception is thrown:

```
    OPartitionedDatabasePool pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(dbUrl, user, password);
    ...
    try (ODatabaseDocumentTx ignored = pool.acquire()) {
        ODocument document = new ODocument(className);
        document.fromJSON(recordData.encode());
        document.field("date", timestamp, OType.DATETIME);
        document.save();
    }
```

Listing clusters shows that cluster 'event_3' is indeed owned by node2:

```
|#   |NAME        |  ID|CLASS     |CONFLICT-STRATEGY|COUNT|OWNER_SERVER|OTHER_SERVERS|AUTO_DEPLOY_NEW_NODE|
|14  |event_1     |  18|event     |                 |    1|  node1     |  [node2]    |        true        |
|15  |event_2     |  19|event     |                 |    1|  node1     |  [node2]    |        true        |
|16  |event_3     |  20|event     |                 |    0|  node2     |  [node1]    |        true        |
```

The insert is successful in other cases, so it looks like the wrong node is selected for insertion only on certain occasions.